# How do you type the undotted i using osx 10.6.7?

Tags: macos, keyboard

In turkish there is a character "ı" which is used frequently. The only way I know of putting it into a text field though is copying it over from somewhere else. I'm assuming the answer has something to do with typing in the correct Option+[...] keys to compose it, but I have no idea what the magic combination is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One [source](http://ask.metafilter.com/135235/Trke) I found said it was <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> (that is, `option+Shift+B`).

---

If you want to find out where all the symbols are on the keyboard, go to *System Preferences - Keyboard* and enable "Show Keyboard Viewer in menu bar". Then click on the new symbol in the upper right menu bar and select "Show Keyboard viewer".

Now you can hold down <kbd>⌥</kbd> and/or <kbd>⇧</kbd> to instantly see all possible characters.

You can also use [Ukulele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=ukelele) to edit your keyboard layout in case you need to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

It varies by keyboard layout, of course.

- **For the U.S. Extended layout:** <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> then <kbd>i</kbd>
- **For the Turkish layout:** It's the <kbd>ı</kbd> key that is on the top alphabetic row between <kbd>ğ</kbd> and <kbd>o</kbd>.
- **For the Turkish Q layout:** It's the <kbd>ı</kbd> key that is on the top alphabetic row between <kbd>u</kbd> and <kbd>o</kbd>.

Comment: I had not previously realized that there was a U.S. "Extended" layout, I had assumed that most characters would be reachable from the U.S. layout.